# Count the threads ended per second

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have some code that spawns a few threads and invokes a Run() method on them.

What I want to do is to embed a timer into that loop which starts the threads and count how many threads have been completed.

The way I want to do that is by creating an entry in a List every time an IStuff is being ran and then count how many elements are in the list every second, and thus produce a per second result.

Not sure if I'm along the correct lines, but please suggest ways of doing that.

Comment: can you post the code you have so far? It would be easier for responders to provide you with a useful answer if they are modifying your existing code rather than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a variable in a shared scope, say `int completionsPerSecond = 0` - and last thing your `Run()` method should do is increment it by 1.

Then you'd have a timer that every second, copies the value in `completionsPerSecond` to show you as your value, and then sets `completionsPerSecond` to 0.

Now every second, you'll know how many finished in the previous second.

Comment: Yep, I've done as far as "incrementing by one", I'm having trouble as to where I should run the timer from. I create it before the foreach(t in threads) loop and invoke it inside the loop, or do I invoke it outside the loop (and since it runs on a separate thread it'll tick every second?)

Comment: If you're incrementing by one, you should be using `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: You'd start it using a `new System.Timer` that you invoke and start (which will run in its own thread) before you start your main workload.